# Changing nvidia powermizer setting using laptop-mode-tools

Tags: linux, nvidia

I have laptop-mode-tools 1.61. The config files at /etc/laptop-mode/ have two folders for making laptop-mode-tools to execute scripts, when it detects that it has been switched from AC to battery, and viceversa. I have nvidia propietary driver 310.14 and ubuntu 12.04. the powermizer setting of the nvidia driver is set to adaptative. I want to have it on adaptative when on battery, and on performance mode (no underclocking) when on AC.

As the powermizer setting is changed in runtime with a selection box, I think it's possible to achieve what I want. 
I have searched the web for commands to change the nvidia powermizer settings on the fly, as with the GUI, but I only found permanent ways of changing it by touching the xorg.conf.

Is there a command to change the nvidia powermizer setting on the fly?